# Different PHP versions got Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a project developed with Codigniter framework and trying to set up in a ubuntu 20.04 server. The application is build under php 5.x and server default is set to php 8.x. Then I got the following error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Filename: core/Controller.php

Line Number: 110

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/cssams2022/application/core/FZ_Controller.php
Line: 10
Function: __construct
```

Line Number: 10 is that "parent::__construct();" in the FZ_Controller.php.
After that error occured, I sat the server defualt php as php5.6 using the following command to be fixed the error.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

But still outs the same error. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: _if (!empty($activity)) {_ and _Trying to access array offset on value of type null_ are very different.

Comment: Which CodeIgniter version? I'd recommend you update to the latest version.

Comment: @  Drk. version 3.x. Pls. see on edit

Comment: I can’t find a version of CI where core/Controller.php has 110 lines of code? What exact version is this?

Comment: That latest version of 3.x is 3.13. Try to ```echo CI_VERSION;``` in any view. 
If it's a lower version, you can go ahead to update CI. As a quick fix, you'll back up the ```system``` folder and replace it with that of the latest version.

Comment: @ Drk. I replaced the system folder by Codeigniter 4 version. Then returned "Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required......./ CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in .........index.php on line 269